# How to identify missing weeks using SQL code?

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to identify specific weeks that are missing in my data. I have multiple states with different date ranges and would like to output all of the missing weeks for the various states that I do have. Not even sure where to begin with a SQL code that would begin to identify missing weeks. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. BTW I'm using SQL Server 2016.
Thanks!

Sample Data:

```
State   WeekEndingDate  Sales
ID       7/5/2015       125000
ID       12/13/2015     127263
IN       8/20/2016      126589
IN       8/27/2016      124568
IN       10/15/2016     119654
MI       01/02/2017     105687
MI       02/05/2017     145962
```

An example of my desired output would be:

```
    MI       01/09/2017     136589
    MI       01/16/2017     125641
    MI       01/23/2017     145769
    MI       01/30/2017     135697
    IN       09/03/2016     145693  and so on....
```

Comment: Missing week in that month?

Comment: One option for you would be is to use a cursor.

Comment: For MI 1/9/2017 ... where are the sales coming from?

Comment: Its coming from the same database. I just have missing weeks for some states. I currently have 2 weeks for MI and want to show all the missing weeks in between those date ranges.

Answer (score 1):

This is what's commonly known as a ["gaps and islands" problem](https://www.sqlshack.com/data-boundaries-finding-gaps-islands-and-more/).

To solve, I strongly suggest you create a [date table](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/12/simply-must-date-table-video/). Then, assuming that you have established that your week ending day is always Saturday, you can include that date table in the query.

```
select MD.state,DT.weekendingdate,MD.sales
from DateTable DT
left outer join MyData MD on DT.Weekendingdate = MD.Weekendingdate
where dt.weekendingdate >= '2016-08-01' and dt.weekendingdate <= '2016-08-31'
```

Comment: Hi Alroc, I do not have special permission to create tables in the database which limits me with the following code. My week ending date also varies for each state that I have in my table. Do you have an alternative solution?

Comment: You can create and populate a temp table. Clumsy, but it'll work - you'll just have to do it every time you run this query. In the temp table, you can give each state its own week ending date and `JOIN` on that field as well..